# Pyspark Fill Missing Values with Decreasing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

My input spark dataframe is;

```
Date        Client  Values
2020-10-26  1       NULL
2020-10-27  1       NULL
2020-10-28  1       NULL
2020-10-29  1       6
2020-10-30  1       NULL
2020-10-31  1       NULL
2020-11-01  1       NULL
2020-11-02  1       NULL
2020-11-03  1       NULL
2020-11-04  1       NULL
2020-11-05  1       NULL
2020-11-06  1       NULL
2020-11-07  1       5
2020-11-08  1       9
2020-11-09  1       NULL
2020-10-26  2       NULL
2020-10-27  2       NULL
2020-10-28  2       NULL
2020-10-29  2       10
2020-10-30  2       6
2020-10-31  2       NULL
2020-11-01  2       NULL
2020-11-02  2       NULL
2020-11-03  2       NULL
2020-11-04  2       NULL
2020-11-05  2       3
2020-11-06  2       NULL
2020-11-07  2       NULL
2020-11-08  2       10
2020-11-09  2       1
```

I want to fill the null values before the non null value in 1 decreasing for each client. This filling process should continue until the value reaches  1 or encounters another non-null value.
I shared the desired output according to the data above;

```
Date        Client  Values
2020-10-26  1       3   .
2020-10-27  1       4   .
2020-10-28  1       5   .
2020-10-29  1       6   -> First non null value after null values. Fill the previous rows in decreasing 1 (5, 4, 3).
2020-10-30  1       NULL
2020-10-31  1       NULL
2020-11-01  1       NULL
2020-11-02  1       NULL
2020-11-03  1       1  .
2020-11-04  1       2  .
2020-11-05  1       3  .
2020-11-06  1       4  .
2020-11-07  1       5  -> First non null value after null values. Fill the previous rows in decreasing 1 (4, 3, 2, 1).
2020-11-08  1       9
2020-11-09  1       NULL
2020-10-26  2       7   .
2020-10-27  2       8   .
2020-10-28  2       9   .
2020-10-29  2       10  -> First non null value after null values. Fill the previous rows in decreasing 1 (9, 8, 7).
2020-10-30  2       6
2020-10-31  2       NULL
2020-11-01  2       NULL
2020-11-02  2       NULL
2020-11-03  2       1
2020-11-04  2       2
2020-11-05  2       3
2020-11-06  2       8
2020-11-07  2       9
2020-11-08  2       10
2020-11-09  2       1
```

Could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy('Client').orderBy('Date')

result = df.withColumn(
    'rn',
    F.row_number().over(w)
).withColumn(
    'rn2',    # get next row number corresponding to non-null Values
    F.first(F.when(F.col('Values').isNotNull(), F.col('rn')), ignorenulls=True)
     .over(w.rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing))
).withColumn(
    'value2',    # get the number you want
    F.first('Values', ignorenulls=True)
     .over(w.rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing))
    + F.col('rn') - F.col('rn2')
).withColumn(
    'Values',
    F.when(F.col('value2') > 0, F.col('value2'))   # only keep positive values
).select(df.columns)

result.show(99,0)
+----------+------+------+
|Date      |Client|Values|
+----------+------+------+
|2020-10-26|1     |3     |
|2020-10-27|1     |4     |
|2020-10-28|1     |5     |
|2020-10-29|1     |6     |
|2020-10-30|1     |null  |
|2020-10-31|1     |null  |
|2020-11-01|1     |null  |
|2020-11-02|1     |null  |
|2020-11-03|1     |1     |
|2020-11-04|1     |2     |
|2020-11-05|1     |3     |
|2020-11-06|1     |4     |
|2020-11-07|1     |5     |
|2020-11-08|1     |9     |
|2020-11-09|1     |null  |
|2020-10-26|2     |7     |
|2020-10-27|2     |8     |
|2020-10-28|2     |9     |
|2020-10-29|2     |10    |
|2020-10-30|2     |6     |
|2020-10-31|2     |null  |
|2020-11-01|2     |null  |
|2020-11-02|2     |null  |
|2020-11-03|2     |1     |
|2020-11-04|2     |2     |
|2020-11-05|2     |3     |
|2020-11-06|2     |8     |
|2020-11-07|2     |9     |
|2020-11-08|2     |10    |
|2020-11-09|2     |1     |
+----------+------+------+
```

Behind the scenes:

```
+----------+------+------+---+----+------+
|Date      |Client|Values|rn |rn2 |value2|
+----------+------+------+---+----+------+
|2020-10-26|1     |3     |1  |4   |3     |
|2020-10-27|1     |4     |2  |4   |4     |
|2020-10-28|1     |5     |3  |4   |5     |
|2020-10-29|1     |6     |4  |4   |6     |
|2020-10-30|1     |null  |5  |13  |-3    |
|2020-10-31|1     |null  |6  |13  |-2    |
|2020-11-01|1     |null  |7  |13  |-1    |
|2020-11-02|1     |null  |8  |13  |0     |
|2020-11-03|1     |1     |9  |13  |1     |
|2020-11-04|1     |2     |10 |13  |2     |
|2020-11-05|1     |3     |11 |13  |3     |
|2020-11-06|1     |4     |12 |13  |4     |
|2020-11-07|1     |5     |13 |13  |5     |
|2020-11-08|1     |9     |14 |14  |9     |
|2020-11-09|1     |null  |15 |null|null  |
|2020-10-26|2     |7     |1  |4   |7     |
|2020-10-27|2     |8     |2  |4   |8     |
|2020-10-28|2     |9     |3  |4   |9     |
|2020-10-29|2     |10    |4  |4   |10    |
|2020-10-30|2     |6     |5  |5   |6     |
|2020-10-31|2     |null  |6  |11  |-2    |
|2020-11-01|2     |null  |7  |11  |-1    |
|2020-11-02|2     |null  |8  |11  |0     |
|2020-11-03|2     |1     |9  |11  |1     |
|2020-11-04|2     |2     |10 |11  |2     |
|2020-11-05|2     |3     |11 |11  |3     |
|2020-11-06|2     |8     |12 |14  |8     |
|2020-11-07|2     |9     |13 |14  |9     |
|2020-11-08|2     |10    |14 |14  |10    |
|2020-11-09|2     |1     |15 |15  |1     |
+----------+------+------+---+----+------+
```